# Нужна помощь в анимации бордера

Tags: css

Нужна анимация для блока, сам бордер начинается с середины левой стороны, обходит весь блок и соединяется с началом.

Comment: svg stroke-dashoffset

Answer (score 1):

Вот анимация: https://jsfiddle.net/uzv3qrd8/
HTML:

```
<div class="block">
  <h3>Block</h3>
  <p>With animated border.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
    .block {
      background: #bbc0c4;
      height: 200px;
      width: 250px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 5px gray;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #848d95;
      border: 10px solid transparent;
      animation: block-border 5s;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      position: relative;
      animation-direction: alternate;
      margin: 10px;
      float: left;
    }

    .block::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: -10px;
      width: 10px;
      height: 0;
      background: #848d95;
      animation: block-before 5s;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-direction: alternate;
    }

    .block::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;

      background: #848d95;
      animation: block-after 5s;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-direction: alternate;
    }

    @keyframes block-border {
      12.5%, 37.4% {
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
      }

      37.5%, 62.4% {
        border-bottom-color: #848d95;
        border-right-color: transparent;
      }

      62.5%, 87.4% {
        border-right-color: #848d95;
        border-top-color: transparent;
      }

      87.5% {
        border-top-color: #848d95;
      }

      to {
        border-bottom-color: #848d95;
        border-right-color: #848d95;
        border-top-color: #848d95;
      }
    }

    @keyframes block-before {
      from {
        height: 0;
      }

      12.5% {
        height: calc(50% + 10px);
      }

      to {
        height: calc(50% + 10px);
      }
    }

    @keyframes block-after {
      12.5% {
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 0;
        height: 10px;
        width: 0;
      }

      37.5% {
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 0;
        height: 10px;
        width: calc(100% + 10px);
      }

      37.6% {
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 100%;
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
      }

      62.5% {
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 100%;
        height: calc(100% + 20px);
        width: 10px;
      }

      62.6% {
        left: 100%;
        bottom: 100%;
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
      }

      87.5% {
        left: -10px;
        bottom: 100%;
        height: 10px;
        width: calc(100% + 20px);
      }

      87.6% {
        left: -10px;
        bottom: 100%;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
      }

      100% {
        left: -10px;
        bottom: calc(50% - 10px);
        width: 10px;
        height: calc(50% + 20px);
      }
    }
```

Использовал псевдоэлементы, но зато HTML-элемент один.